# ¿Cómo puedo desinstalar un paquete instalado con pip?

Tags: python, pip

Con frecuencia me encuentro probando nuevos paquetes con Pip. Qué fácil es hacer un `pip install <paquete>` y probarlo. Luego al rato lo mismo me doy cuenta de que el paquete no me va a ser útil, por lo que quiero desinstalarlo.

¿Cómo desinstalo un paquete con pip?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tal y como se detalla en [pip uninstall](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_uninstall/), simplemente debes decir:

```
pip uninstall paquete
```

También puedes usar alguna de estas opciones:

- Leer el listado de un fichero "fichero":

  ```
  pip uninstall -r fichero
  ```
- Dar "sí" automáticamente a las preguntas de confirmación que se formulen:

  ```
  pip uninstall -y
  ```
- O combinarlas, claro:

  ```
  pip uninstall -y -r fichero
  ```

---

Si quieres desinstalar todos los paquetes que has instalado, di:

```
pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

Pues `pip freeze` lista todos los paquetes instalados y `xargs` los coge uno a uno pasándoselos a `pip uninstall`.

Answer (score 0):

sí necesitas eliminar todos los paquetes que has instalado en windows PowerShell la equivalencia seria:

```
pip freeze | ForEach-Object { pip uninstall -y $_ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tienen problemas con los comandos de arriba, el siguiente comando me funcionó de maravilla en windows:

```
for /F "delims==" %i in ('pip freeze') do pip uninstall -y %i
```