# ¿Cómo usar módulos en Visual Studio Code?

Tags: vscode

Buen día, tengo una duda, no sé cómo usar módulos externos en Visual Studio Code.

Estoy tomando un curso para Python y en él debemos instalar y usar el módulo `camelcase`, solo que el que da el curso mostró cómo hacerlo en Mac y no en Windows. Además él usa Nvim y yo Visual Studio Code.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?, en teoría ya instalé `camelcase`, solo que no lo puedo implementar y no sé cómo solucionarlo.

Les adjunto una imagen para que puedan ver, hasta abajo dice `'No module named camelcase'` aunque ya lo tenga

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, asegurate de haber instalado camelcase, abre la linea de comando de VS Code, y pega los siguientes comandos (Asegurandote que la ubicación de la consola es tu repositorio)

- `pip3 uninstall camelcase`

[Desinstalalo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/261810/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-desinstalar-un-paquete-instalado-con-pip) para asegurarte que la instalación será limpia

- `pip3 install camelcase`

Luego debe de ir el código descrito en la [documentación](https://pypi.org/project/camelcase/) como ejemplo de uso

```
from camelcase import CamelCase
c = CamelCase()
s = 'this is a sentence that needs CamelCasing!'
print c.hump(s) #Se que tienes practicamente lo mismo, pero prueba
```

Que te aparezca rayado verde solo significa que, alguna extensión que tienes, no le cuadra ese nombre, no ve que sea algo bien escrito, no te asustes por eso.
Prueba primero el ejemplo básico y luego trata de hacerlo como lo necesitas

Comment: La linea de comandos de visual studio es la que aparece abajo cuando ejecutas el código, ¿verdad?

Comment: @ImGuzmn Sii, puedes asegurarte que estas en ella en el menú de `Terminal` en la parte superior, el séptimo de izquierda a derecha.

Comment: Ya lo he hecho, pero me deja igual :(

Comment: @ImGuzmn actualizé, prueba con `pip3` para indicar que usas python3

Comment: Lo acabo de intentar y tampoco me deja, ¿será más fácil en Pycharm?

Comment: @ImGuzmn No, la idea de estos editores de texto es que no tengas que cargar un IDE completo... Y por tu codigo, tus nombres y demás, creo que tomamos el mismo tutorial de HolaMundo con Nicolas. Revisa tu versión de python con `python -V` en la linea de comandos

Comment: Jajaja si, es el mismo, que bueno que tú si pudiste hacerlo. Ya lo hice con Pycharm y se pudo, pero con Visual Studio no